# Past perfect of "have"?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

What is the past perfect of "have"? Is it

"have",

"had", or

"had had"?

And if it is "had had",

doesn't it sound weird and awkward?

when and how do I use it?

Thanks.

Comment: yeah sounds awkward to me like someone stammering..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had had my doubts about his performance for some time, but when he messed up his latest project, I decided to fire him.

The past perfect is *had had*, you use it whenever you would normally use a past perfect, and as long as you use it correctly, I don't feel it sounds weird or awkward at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a non-native speaker it may sound awkward indeed, but you get used to it easily. Anyway its use has been decreasing in recent decades as shown in the graph reported in the link below from Google Ngram.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+had&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20had%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This completely fails to say what is the past perfect of "have", which is **have had**. It may be included in the Ngram but one day that site or link may no longer be visible.

Answer (score 0):

In *had had*, they are actually two conceptually different words.

the first functions as an auxiliary verb. The second as an idiomatic replacement of an actual verb.

*Had* is usually used to idiomatically replace actual verbs.

- He *had* me for a moment.
  He *bluffed* me for a moment.
- He *had* her last night.
  He *copulated with* her last night.
- I am *having* my breakfast. I *had* cereals for breakfast.
  I am *eating* my breakfast. I *ate* cereals for breakfast
- She *had* him in her pocket.
  She *placed* him under her control.
- I *had* a good time.
  I *enjoyed* a good time.

Therefore, when you need to express the perfect

- He has *had* her for a decade.
  He has *participated in intimacy with* for a decade.
  He had *had* her for years before he died.
  I had *had* a good time.

Certain words require an auxiliary verb to take effect.

- I had intimate moments with him.
  **perfected**: I have had intimate moments with him.
- I have painful memories.
  **present perfected**: I have had painful memories.
  **past perfected**: I had had painful memories.
- He has an attitude.
  **present perfected**: He has had an attitude.
  **subjunctive present perfected**: He would have an attitude.
  **past perfected**: He had had an attitude.